# Specifiy sslmode in Bitnami Keycloak Helm chart

Tags: postgresql, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm currently working on redirecting an existing Keycloak instance to an existing (but empty) PostgreSQL database. To deploy Keycloak we are using the [Bitnami Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/keycloak), which worked great so far. My only problem is that I cannot find an option to specify `sslmode=require` in the chart.

I've specified the database options in the values.yml like this (credentials are being added at a later stage):

```
externalDatabase:
  host: host
  port: 5432
  database: postgres
```

I've tried adding it to the database name like `database: postgres?sslmode=require` but that messed up Keycloaks process to recognize it being a PostgreSQL database and resulted in Keycloak using its h2 database.

Since I'm able to connect to that database with my local keycloak instance, I tried deploying a 'ready-to-go' standalone-ha.xml to the pod and then tried changing the `KEYCLOAK_CONF_FILE` value in the values.yml:

```
extraEnvVars:
  - name: 'KEYCLOAK_CONF_FILE'
    value: '/custom/standalone-ha.xml'
```

But that didn't work either.

Disabling SSL is not an option.

**Update:**

Since `KEYCLOAK_CONF_FILE` seemed to be the wrong variable, I've tried using `KEYCLOAK_MOUNTED_CONF_DIR` and added my prebuild standalone-ha.xml to it. Apparently that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a github issue here: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/6217

It seems like the feature doesn't exist.